# How should files for AWS AssetCode be excluded now?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I used to do this:

```
    const fn = new lambda.Function(this, "MyLambda", {
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X,
      handler: "index.handler",
      code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, "../lambda"), {
        exclude: ["cdk", "*.ts"],
      }),
    });
```

But the AWS CDK doc flagged `exclude` as deprecated without providing a means to replace it. Is there a new mechanism now or should I come up with my own solution (e.g. create a clean folder)?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-s3-assets.AssetOptions.html#excludespan-classapi-icon-api-icon-deprecated-titlethis-api-element-is-deprecated-its-use-is-not-recommended%EF%B8%8Fspan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you need to do, looks like there is an effort to move assets classes to core.  The aws-lambda package uses aws-s3-assets AssetOptions which still uses CopyOptions from assets and not core CopyOptions.  Once they do you won't see that warning.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/7708